# How do I show that $Im\int_{r}^{s}f(t)dt=\int_{r}^{s}Imf(t)dt ?$

Tags: complex-analysis

$I=[a,b]$ with $a<b$ is compact range in $\mathbb R$.

It is also given that $f,g \in C(I)$ and $r,s\in I$. $C(I)$ is quantity of all in $I$ continuous functions.
$I=[a,b]$ with $a<b$ is compact range in $\mathbb R$.

It is also given that $f,g \in C(I)$ and $r,s\in I$. $C(I)$ is quantity of all in $I$ continuous functions.

How do I show that $Im\int_{r}^{s}f(t)dt=\int_{r}^{s}Imf(t)dt ?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align} &\Im\left(\int_{r}^{s}f(t)dt\right)\\&= \Im\left(\int_{r}^{s}\Re(f(t))+i \Im(f(t)) dt\right)\\&= 
\Im\left(\int_{r}^{s}\Re(f(t))\right)+ \Im \left( \int_r^s i \Im(f(t)) dt\right)\\
&= 0 + \Im \left( i\int_r^s  \Im(f(t)) dt\right)
\\&=\int_{r}^{s}\Im (f(t))dt \end{align}